# In Pine Script, how can I make ta.cross enter at a specified price during backtesting, instead of entering at the close of the candle?

Tags: pine-script

I am aware that by enabling calc_on_every_tick, I can achieve immediate entry upon ta.cross meeting a specified price during live trading. However, the problem is that during backtesting, entries still occur only at the close of the candle, making the backtesting data very inaccurate and preventing me from confidently running quantitative trades. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Additionally, I'd like to ask if it's better to use varip instead of var when calc_on_every_tick is enabled, to avoid the issue of receiving a large number of abnormal alerts at the time of entry.

```
//sample colse
ma20 = ma(close, 20)
longCodition = close > ma20
if longCodition and ta.crossunder(low,  ma20)
   strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
```

Comment: How do you choose the price that you want to be crossed?

Comment: Updated example code provided.